# How to join 2 collection in query laravel

Tags: laravel, join, collections

I have StudentEducation model and in this model i got

```
public function student_education_countries()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StudentEducationCountry::class, 'education_id');
}
```

and

```
public function student_education_education_types()
{
    return $this->hasMany(StudentEducationEducationType::class, 'education_id');
}
```

in StudentEducationCountry model i got

```
public function student_education()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(StudentEducation::class, 'education_id');
}

public function student_country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(StudentCountry::class, 'country_id');
}
```

and in StudentEducationEducationType model i got

```
public function student_education()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(StudentEducation::class, 'education_id');
}
public function student_educationcategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(StudentEducationcategory::class, 'educationcategory_id');
}
```

The question is how should i join for to take all educations where country_id is 2  and type is secondary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple with whereHas()

```
$educations = StudentEducation::query()->whereHas('student_education_countries', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('id', 2);
})->whereHas('student_education_education_types', function (Builder $query) {
    //maybe here you need another columns
    $query->where('type', 'secondary');
})->get();
```